# Zooming PDFViewWPF by touch gestures

Tags: c#, touch, pdfnet

We've got an application which was running with PDFNet.dll in version 6.3.2. Zooming by touch gestures was working properly.
Since we've updated PDFNet to Version 6.8.2 (and the newest PDFNetTools) it doesn't work anymore. Touch handling in general works without problems, but not zooming a pdf in or out.

I've found a possible solution in a [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pdfnet-sdk/h-hzWvPAK-E/4qxD6qi-Uk4J) which is mentioning to set

```
_PdfView.IsManipulationEnabled = true;
```

which is exactly what we've done before (6.3.2) and already doing with the newer version of PDFNet. Sadly this doesn't help.

Are there other hints or solutions to fix this problem?

The same applies to drawing annotations with an Microsoft Surface Pen, but I think both relate to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tested for this issue with version 6.3.2, 6.8.3 and 6.9.0. I was not able to find v6.8.2 in our regular stable releases.

Zooming gesture worked in all cases. Can you please try one of our sample projects to see if you can reproduce the issue? A good one for your case would be PDFViewWPFTest sample.

In any case, I would highly recommend you to upgrade to the latest SDK version from our website:
https://www.pdftron.com/downloads/

Please let us know if this resolves your issue or if you have any questions.

-Yasser, PDFTron Systems Inc.

Comment: Your test application works with all mentioned versions (6.3.2, 6.8.2 and 6.9.1 (seems to be the newest version)). In our application it doesn't work with 6.9.1, too.

Comment: Since this seems tied to your project, can you please send us your minimal project that reproduces the issue. Alternatively, you can modify our sample project to reproduce the issue.

In case you don't want to send the project here, you can directly send it to us using the following link:
https://www.pdftron.com/form/report-bug

Comment: You can use the following link instead of the previous one: https://www.pdftron.com/form/request

Comment: Since it is not possible to send you our code and I was not able to reproduce the issue on the example project, I gave it another try. I want to retract my statement partially. Touch-Zooming IS possible, but only on ToolType `pan`. This may be a problem in our application - I will investigate this. But writing with an Surface Pencil isn't possible even if you example application. Maybe you could check this.

Comment: Thank you for bringing the Surface Pen issue to our attention. We were able to reproduce the issue. 

We will add support for Surface Pen in the next WPF update. If you are current user please get in touch with us so that we can provide you with pre-release version. Thank you again.

Comment: We are a current user, but we don't need it that fast. Thank you. For now we removed the 4 lines of code in the ToolManager.Evaluate method which canceled all events for stylus devices. It's no real surface pen support, but for the moment it's ok for us.